# Find the absolute maximum and the absolute minimum values of $f$ on the given interval and sketch the graph by hand: $f(x):=x^4-2x^2+3$, [-2,3]

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the absolute maximum and the absolute minimum values of f on the given interval and sketch the graph by hand: $$f(x):=x^4-2x^2+3\quad{}[-2,3]$$
Ive found the derivative of this function $$4x^3-4x=4x(x^2-1)$$
$$x_1=0, x_2=+1,-1$$

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. Good work replacing your image with proper Mathjax like the other maths above. For future reference, it's a quality requirement. 

Comment: draw a table of signs,where on the second line u have the sign of $x$ and the third line , the sign of $x^{2}-1$ and then on the fourth line the product of the signs,this will give u the sign of the derivative in terms of $x$,then u draw the variations of $f$ in order to determine maximum and minimum.

Comment: @belkacemabderrahmane fmax=66; fmin=2 ?

Comment: It is important to note that the maximum and minimum of a function can occur where the derivative is zero, but also on the boundary of the interval. So in this case you have to check not only $-1$, $0$ and $1$, but also $-2$ and $3$.